# call a javascript/jquery function from JointJS Element/Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jointjs

I created a hyperlink element by jointjs. Now, I want to call a function from this element.
My Code is here:

```
new joint.shapes.custom.ElementLabelLink({
                        id: node.id.toString(),
                        size: { width: width, height: height },
                        attrs: {
                             a: { 'xlink:href': 'https://www.google.co.in', 'xlink:show': 'new', cursor: 'pointer''},
                            text: { 
                              text: formattedNodeName, 
                              'font-size': letterSize, 
                              'font-family': 'Inspira',
                              'x-alignment': 'middle'},
                            rect: {
                                width: width, height: height,
                                rx: 5, ry: 5,
                                stroke: '#555',
                                fill: 'lightgreen' 
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

In this code, what I have to add or there is some other way.
What I am trying to do, this is feasible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution for my query. I am posting answer here; by which someone can get help. No need to do anything with Element or Link. 
Just executed an event on paper div.
Here is the code:

```
 paper.on('cell:pointerdblclick',function(cellView, evt, x, y) {
     demo();
  });

function demo(){
 alert("1");
}
```

I am doing too many things inside pointerdblclick event call. Here is the idea by which some one can get help.